# History Question: DB2 Nomenclature

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I realize this is a little random, but DB2 (circa V8) had a feature to define tables from the `CREATE VIEW` syntax.  Basically, the view was saved to disk to save the cost of recreating the dataset each time the view is called.

All I really need to know is what was this feature called?  I was thinking it was Federated Views, but that seems to be about incorporating external data into the database.  Would this work for saving aggregated data from within a database or is there another name for this feature?

Please help an old guy out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of *Materialized Query Tables* or MQTs.  They are still part of the product, see [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0061577.html).

Comment: BTW they were called _Automatic Summary Tables_ in their first incarnation (circa DB2 UDB v5.2 !), they got renamed to MQTs in V8.1  I think